# How to I remove duplicates from my SQL SELECT results?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

I have a basic SQL SELECT query that returns results which have duplicates.  I want to eliminate the duplicates entirely.  For example, the results show the following values for EQNum:

```
200
157
135
200
146
```

I want the results to eliminate 200 entirely and leave me with

```
157
135
146
```

I have tried SELECT DISTINCT but this leave a single 200 entry.  It seems like a basic request, but I am unable to find a working solution.

Comment: could you post the select statement?

Comment: distinct is row related, not field related, please post sql

Answer (score 6):

You could `group by` the value and then examine the `count(*)` in the `having` clause.

E.g., assuming your original query is a simple `select value from mytable` you could do the following:

```
SELECT   value
FROM     mytable
GROUP BY value
HAVING   COUNT(*) = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
select * 
from table 
where val not in 
(select val from 
   (select val, count(*) cnt 
   from table group by val) 
   where cnt > 1
)
```